# Why does the errorlevel keeps changing to 1?

Tags: windows, batch-file, printing, windows-10

I have a txt file listing the ports that have printers plugged in on my computer and a `findstr` to look it up and set one or the other as default printers based upon a string of caracters is found or not in the txt file. The command for setting the default printers are working fine outside of the if clause, but, aparently the `findstr` is unable to find the string. What am I missing here?

Everytime I run it, it sets the SamsungM printer as the default one, because the `ERRORLEVEL` is always set to `1` after running the `findstr`. Prior to it, it was set to `0`.

The code:

```
findstr /I "usb001" ports.txt
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (wmic printer where portname="USB001" call setdefaultprinter) else (wmic printer where "PortName like '%%samsungm'" call setdefaultprinter)
```

The txt file:

```
PortName              
USB001                
\\ses267827\samsungm  
172.22.41.49
```

Comment: What is the encoding of `ports.txt`?

Comment: @aschipfl I'm just looking into this, now. Apparently cmd is saving automatically on UTF-16 LE. I think it might work out if i can get cmd to save as ANSI.

Comment: By what command (line) are you generating `ports.txt` -- `wmic`? `wmic` returns Unicode data; `cmd` (and so its internal commands) does not unless you specify the `/U` option...

Comment: Yeah. The problem was the encoding. I changed the code to include the pipeing directly from the ```wmic``` code and it worked fine. Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type file.txt | findstr /bi "USB001" && (
    echo wmic printer where portname="USB001" call setdefaultprinter
) || (
    echo wmic printer where "PortName like '%%samsungm'" call setdefaultprinter
)
```

`wmic printer get portname` outputs unicode so the file would be UTF16-LE encoding. Try piping `type file.txt` to `findstr` which may decode it better for `findstr` to handle.

If you can view the file in a hex editor, you may notice nuls `00` next to each character. That is an indication of 2 bytes per character, so it will be unicode, as ANSI is 1 byte per character.

Or you could pipe from `wmic`:

```
wmic printer get portname | findstr /bi "USB001" && (
    echo wmic printer where portname="USB001" call setdefaultprinter
) || (
    echo wmic printer where "PortName like '%%samsungm'" call setdefaultprinter
)
```

which appears that `findstr` handles the piped stream OK.

Comment: The problem was, indeed, the encoding. The ```type``` sugestion didn't work out, but pipeing the ```wmic``` resolved the issue. Thank you so much!